# It is possible to know when a switch between branches was made in a working copy?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a working copy which is now pointing to a erroneous branch.

I want to know when a switch was made to this working copy from the previous and correct branch to the current and erroneous branch.

I tried with svn log but I can  see just the full log of the changes done in the current erroneous branch. These changes are since the creation of the branch, so I just am seeing changes on the repository, not in the working copy.

It is possible to know when a switch between branches was made in a working copy?

Answer (score 0):

If you used TortoiseSVN to perform the switch and it wasn't too long ago, check the [action log](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-saved-data).  This would give you date/time and the revision that was switched *to*, but not revision that was switched *from*:

```
4/1/2016 - 1:22:31 PM
Command              : Switch C:\My\Working\Copy to http://svn.myserver.com/My/Repository, Revision HEAD
...
Completed            : At revision: 73153
800 kBytes transferred in 0 minute(s) and 7 second(s)
```

SVN itself doesn't keep track of that information, that I'm aware of.  Since it would be client-side data (due to being in a working copy), only a few commands could possibly be aware of it: `info`, `log`, and `list`.  And none of these commands have any way to list any information like that.

Comment: I'm not using tortoise